# Отправка письма с помощью javaMail

Tags: java, android, javamail

Прошу помощи в обращении с классом `javax.mail`.

Написано приложение под Андроид, которое мониторит почтовый ящик и посылает ответы. Если посылаю письмо с одного gmail-ящика на другой gmail-ящик, то всё ОК. Если с ящика mail.ru, то посылать письма не получается.

Ошибка:

```
E/MailApp: Could not send email 501 5.5.4 Invalid argument
```

Вот код:

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Log.d("Trying send", "host="+_host);
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;        
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.ru");        
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", "mymail@mail.ru");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

}
```

Как хотя бы узнать, что конкретно не нравится серверу?

Повторюсь, если отправляю с gmail-ящика письмо, то всё нормально работает (разумеется, меняю адрес smtp-сервера)

Вот лог SMTP:

```
I/System.out: DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.ru", port 465, isSSL false
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 533K, 6% free 10131K/10696K, paused 22ms, total 24ms
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.mail.ru", port: 465
E/MailApp: Could not send email 501 5.5.4 Invalid argument
```

Comment: Попробуйте [сократить пример кода до минимального](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Малый пример, демонстрирующий проблему, привлечёт больше людей, которые смогут вам помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, сократил.

Comment: Не удалось воспроизвести на эмуляторе, хотя в текущем виде код требует правок для запуска (до "минификации" он хотя бы компилировался). javax.mail-1.4.7. Пробовал посылать и с адреса с включенной двухфакторной аутентификацией, и без. Единственное, что новый ящик не регистрировал. Попробуйте зайти в веб-интерфейс ящика, с которого отправляете. Еще javamail в отладочном режиме пишет в консоль весь диалог с сервером, можно посмотреть, что последнее отправлялось на сервер, до его ответа `501`.

Comment: Да, после "минимизации кода" он стал не компилируемым. zRrr, у вас всё нормально отработало с mail.ru-ящиком?
Зачем заходить на maul.ru ящик через броузер? Разумеется, я имею к нему доступ. Может действительно что-то в настройках ящика поменять?

Answer (score 1):

> smtp.mail.ru, port 465, isSSL false

А если попробовать с isSSL = true либо с 25 портом ?